# MVC — Show user's information from database into TextBoxFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I found countless links online for getting a value from a textbox in `View` but none for getting a value from the `database` **into** the textbox. I need to show the user's profile information so that he can edit them. I'm sure it's easy... as long as you know how! Any idea? Thanks in advance!

**View**

```
@model Project.Models.membre

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Profil", "Membres", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @Value = ???????? })
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```cs
public ActionResult Profil()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Will you include your controller code? Since you have a model attached in your view, we need to assign a value to Model.Name.

Comment: I see, ok last step, will you include the full view code? I need the @ Model that is declared at the top of the view.

Comment: Yes that's what I needed, thanks. I'll make an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to assign value to that; We could either

- Assign the value in the controller
- Assign the value in the view

You could use either of the two.

To assign a value to model.Name in the view, razor framework allows you to interact with objects or write programming code using @{ //Your code here }

```
@model Project.Models.membre

@{
  // Write your code here
  model.Name = "Pensum"
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Profil", "Membres", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name)
    </div>
}
```

OR

To assign a value to model.Name in the controller, we should first instantiate an object (membre object) then assign a value to it then pass it to the view.

```
using Project.Models;

public ActionResult Profil()
{
    // instantiate object
    membre m = new membre();

    // assign value to property
    m.Name = "Pensum";

    // pass to the view
    return View(m);
}
```

---

*EDIT from OP (with database solution)*

```
public ActionResult Profil(membre user)
{
    var session = Session["login"];

    using(database db = new database())
    {
        var userdb = db.membre.Where(x => x.login == session).FirstOrDefault;
        user.Name = userdb.Name;
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: *Me to myself* — See? So easy... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its easy with your Razor view HTML controls.

The thing you missed is to pass the model from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Profil()
{
    var user = dbContext.Members.Where(m=>m.loginid == Session["loginid"]).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(user);
}
```

Please use proper type casting of the session variable as of your database field type.
And in view, I think waht you did will work!

Comment: How is `int id` passed? I tried passing the `user` class as paramater but the properties are set to null. I'm not sure where I can set their values.

Comment: Can you show me from where you are calling the "Profil" Action?

Comment: It is from the navbar in a layout.. So basically, from 3 or 4 possible views that wear this layout. `<li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Profil", "Profil", "Membres", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>`

Comment: I assume, the page is showing the profile of the current user. If so, you have stored the current/logged in user's data in somewhere (may be in cookie/session). You can get the user id or at least any unique data of the user. What is your case?

Comment: I just used a session variable `Session["login"] = login username`. I use it to do a query and get the property values. I don't know how to set the user's values before as he logs in. Do I create a new instance of user in the home controller which will be passed implicitely when clicking on the ActionLink? Because I don't send the paramater like we do in the console for example. Like I said, I'm logging in by checking in a query, go to profil, do another query to get the user's values.... It's not really optimal.

Comment: I think, I'm failing to understand your case. My Bad. I'm trying to clear you about something: 1) A logged in user clicked to see his/her profile. In that case we must have the login id of that user in the session variable (as you stated). We can fire a  query to get that user from the database and pass that to the view. 2) Admin/Any user trying to see a member profile. In this case, s/he needs to provide the user id/name to determine which user's profile to show.

Comment: `public ActionResult Profil(member user) { }` — I don't understand where the parameter user is passed. It's not like I wrote some code `Profil(myaccount);` I just clicked on an ActionLink that is calling a controller. So where do I have to set the values of the parameter to pass? As of right now, it's null. I am doing a second query to get the values of `user` by searching with his session id. The first one was to check if the login was valid... Shouldn't I just be able to save the user's values upon logging in and then just use the values in the profile instead of having to do a second query?

Comment: It works too, but it still doesn't explain why I can pass a parameter in the controller if I'm never using it. I have to do a query to find out which user is logged in to get his profile information. It's not practical imo since I already know which user is connected.

Comment: The controller action here is not getting a parameter. If you know which user is logged in, just get the user details as a model and pass it to the view (as my answer shows).